# not shown design of application properly in landscape mode

Tags: android

In app is shown as like this  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b0c2d2f in simple mode,
but in landscape mode this is shown as like this http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d109510

for simple

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bowlbackground" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hkk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp" >

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="143dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

for landscape

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bowlbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hkk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
     >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can check in the Eclipse it self while you design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you rotate your phone the Activity restarts, which probably calls something that causes your images again somehow. This is part of the OS and a bit annoying, here is that to do.

If you in your manifest add:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the activity node in which the rotation is done, you'll have to override the onConfigurationChanged.

```
 @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use relative layouts, not linear layouts with margins. You never know the screen size of the user's phone, so even if using dip/dp, its not safe to assume how it'll look.

With relative layouts, you can specify that each item should be below, or to the right of another item/layout.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the the information you provided is enough or not.But try using different images in drawable for both the layouts.